Could this vector field exists on a manifold?
I want to "generalize" the smooth flow $F(t,x)=e^{t}x$ on a Riemannian manifold in the following sense:
Let (M,p) be a pointed positive dimensional smooth complete Riemannian manifold (that is, p is an element of M). I want to know if it is possible to construct a vector field X on M with the following properties:

The set of zeros is discrete, and $X(p)=0$.
The set where X is non-smooth is discrete.
If $F(t,x)$ is the flow where it is defined, then $d_g(F(t,x),p)\leq e^{t}d_g(x,p)$ for all x where $X(x)$ is non-zero, and $d_g$ is the Riemannian distance function.

Note that the condition 3) implies that every maximal integral curve "ends" in $p$. In particular, there cannot be any periodic integral curve (all maximal integral curves are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$). If $q$ is a zero of X, then its integral curve is constant, so $d_g(F(t,q),p)>e^t d_g(q,p)$ for t non-positive, but such point can be ignored for my purposes. In the Euclidean case, $F(t,x)=e^t(x-p)+p$ satisfies all 3 conditions (all curves emerges from $p$). Another example: I can prove that we can modify the previous flow $F$ on $\mathbb{S}^2/{N}$ using stereographic coordinates, and then defining $X$ to be zero on $N$ such that the three conditions are satisfied. The idea is to take normal geodesic coordinates around the south pole $S$, define G to be an "slower" flow that F in those coordinates (this depends on the metric, but it can be done), and then extend the integral curves smoothly into the north pole $N$ using geodesics.
I believe it is more practical to start with a coordinate ball $B$ centered on $p$, define the flow $e^tx$ on coordinates (modulo constant so that property 3) holds) and then try to join almost all points with a geodesic in a unique way.
I`m not looking for a precise answer since this question is very specific. I will appreciate any ideas about a possibly construction or for a counterexample.
Here are some ideas/questions to look:
a) It is known that if the manifold $M$ is open, then there exists a non-vanishing vector field X. Using an smooth real function $f$, we could define $fX$ where $f^{-1}(0)=p$, so that $X$ only has one zero. Could this zero be constructed so that the maximal integral curves emerges from $p$? Then, it would be a simply matter of controling the velocity of the curves.
b) Imitating the $\mathbb{S}^2$ example, maybe we can create a vector field (not necessarily continuous) with exactly two zeros, one from where the curves emerges, and the other where the curves goes in.

Do you care only about $t\ge 0$. If (3) holds for all $t$, then $p$ is the only zero of $X$.

Sorry, I edited condition (3), I only care that the condition holds for non-vanishing points.
